# Working with json response from rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json

I'm almost there but can't seem to debug this simple item.

I have page with:

```
<div id="count">
```

I am using the following function to get the count from the server:

```
$.get("/count?post_id=" + postId, function(post_count) {
    $('#count').html(post_count.count);
```

And the response from the server is:

```
[{"count":0}]
```

But, the page does not update with the count supplied.  I used to have the response render simple text and the page was updating with the new count as expected but I can't get it to work when using json.

Can anyone please lend a hand?

EDIT 1

When I do

```
alert(post_count)
```

I get an alert dialogue with [object][Object]

However, when I try to do

```
alert(post_count.count)
```

I get an alert dialogue with Undefined.

Is the JSON format as noted above correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the response is `[{"count":0}]` then it looks like:

```
post_count.count
```

should be:

```
post_count[0].count
```

since it is an array containing an object/hash.

Also, consider using existing frameworks like [restful_json](https://github.com/garysweaver/restful_json) and [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) to do the heavy lifting once you go beyond simple calls like this. An example of using those two projects together is the [employee-training-tracker](https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/employee-training-tracker) app. There other Javascript frameworks that also hide this sort of complexity. Some are listed in the [TodoMVC](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/) page with examples. And, look into using [rails-api](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api) if you write your own service controllers.

Comment: I actually just figured that out (the JSON response was wrapped in an array) and changed it on the Rack side to send the first array item.  Anyway, your solution works as well so I'm marking it correct.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Rails application response with JSON, not only in the content but also the headers:

try:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json=> whatever.to_json }
end
```

Edit: Missed this before but when calling JSON with jQuery to have it automagically parse(instead of using JSON.parse(response) use:

```
$.getJSON(url, function(){});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is actually a rack application for my Rails site...I have the response header set as {"Content-Type" => "appication/json"}

Comment: Thanks again!  I tried getJSON but same thing happens.  Anyway, according to jQuery .get() api, I should be able to parse JSON with a standard .get.